# Distribution of java project containing javadb made in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I've just completed my java application & am now trying to distribute it. The build works fine, but when tried on another PC I receive the error:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException
>   : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message
>   Connection refused: connect.

The code being run is

```
         try
    {
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db01", "Administrator", "admin"); //run procedure getConnection to connect to the database - see below
    PreparedStatement st =conn.prepareStatement("Select * from TB01");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
   jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
    }
```

I'm assuming that I'm missing something for setting parameters for when the code is run outside of IDE.  Could anyone please explain to me what else I have to include?

TB01 is just a table containing some sample data, that I am trying to display on the gui.  It works perfectly from within IDE

It does not work on my pc once I have closed IDE.  Do you have to include some code to start the server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use JavaDB in an embedded mode. Then you don't need to start the server and no network traffic is needed. I think it's called "Java DB (Embedded)" in Netbeans.

Here is an old howto: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/embedded_database_for_netbeans_platform